# NODEJS Game data transmission in real time

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io, transmission

To practice I am trying to develop a multiplayer game. I'm using NODEJS and HTML5 canvas. To share data between client and server I'm using Socket.io

What I would to know is how to optimize the client-server data transmission.

**INFO**

- The player is moving all the time and I have to update player position every 1000/60 ms (60 fps).
- The player movements:

```canvas
    vecX = mouse.x - player.x;
    vecY = mouse.y - player.y;
    vec = Math.sqrt(vecX*vecX + vecY*vecY);

    dx = vecX/vec;
    dy = vecY/vec;

    player.x += dx*player.speed;
    player.y += dy*player.speed;
```

- What I tried?

1st Try:

- Client sends mouse position to server for each mouse movement.
- Server saves mouse position
- Server refreshes players position (by each player mouse position) every 1000/60 ms and retrieves it to every player that has it's position on his screen (screen just show a part of map).

-> Problem: lagging a lot.

2nd Try:

- Client sends dx and dy to the server for each mouse movement (not the mouse position).
- Server retrieves this dx and dy to every player.
- Client moves each player by it's dx and dy.
- Server moves each player by it's dx and dy (just refreshing server-side data).
- Server retrieves players position each 100 ms (correcting position).

-> Problem: unsynchronized data

Comment: usually for game streaming, with less lag they will implement UDP instead of TCP/IP connection (socket.io uses TCP/IP), tried UDP?

Comment: @Tim how can we configure socket.io or nodeJS to use UDP ?

Comment: Check out webrtc